# ubuntu 20.04 update seems to run grub-install

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, grub2

I had my main Ubuntu 20.04 on partition /dev/nvme0n1p6 and a newer experimental/fun Ubuntu 20.04 on partition /dev/nvme0n1p7. Because the experimental/fun Ubuntu 20.04 on partition /dev/nvme0n1p7 was newer than /dev/nvme0n1p6, it was the last one (afik) to do a 'grub-install', and so it was the first entry, listed as 'Ubuntu' in the boot menu, and the main one was number 4 on the grub menu and was listed like 'Ubuntu 20.04 /dev/nvme0n1p6'.

Then I did a update/upgrade on main Ubuntu 20.04 on partition /dev/nvme0n1p6, and now it's as if there was a 'grub-install' somehow happened.  Now the grub menu is flipped. The first entry, listed as 'Ubuntu' is for /dev/nvme0n1p6, and number 4 listed like 'Ubuntu 20.04 /dev/nvme0n1p7.

What did i do wrong? How could I have avoided this? thanks

Comment: I don’t think you did anything wrong. Some update/upgrades require an update-grub process to be run. That would happen if the kernel was upgraded so you cannot really avoid it. Just do an update-grub from the install that you want to manage grub after upgrading the other install.

Comment: Thank you Ponjar